# SharePoint - Hard limit on # of calculated columns in a list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Has anyone by chance hit a hard limit of 51 calculated columns in a list in MOSS2007? Is this documented anywhere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the column limits for MOSS 2007:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#Column
For calculated it says you should be getting 48 calced columns (8 per database row and the default situation is to use up to 6 database rows to represent 1 list item).